# Using django-import-export together with django-parler

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export, django-parler

I'm trying to import and export models using `django-import-export` while having `TranslatedFields` from `django-parler`.

Although I explicitly added `Description` to the Meta fields in `ChildInsurancePlanResource` it's not showing up when importing items. `Name` is showing up.

I don't know how to make `django-import-export` recognize those fields and import them as the default language.

My admin.py looks like this:

```py
class ChildInsurancePlanResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = InsurancePlan
        fields = (
            "id",
            "Name",
            "Description"
        )

class ChildInsurancePlanAdmin(TranslatableAdmin, PolymorphicChildModelAdmin, ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ChildInsurancePlanResource

    base_form = TranslatableModelForm
    base_model = InsurancePlan


admin.site.register(ChildInsurancePlan, ChildInsurancePlanAdmin)
```

The model is defined like this:

```py
class InsurancePlan(PolymorphicModel):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class ChildInsurancePlan(InsurancePlan, TranslatableModel):
    objects = InsurancePlanManager()

    translations = TranslatedFields(
        Description=models.TextField(_("Description"), max_length=5000),
    )
```

Comment: Do you have a solution yet?